Visual Studio hint, while working with C# classes
In my C# program, I have the following source code:
if ((Int32.Parse(u_Message.PK1)

When hovering my mouse above the word Int32, this is what I see:

I'm especially interested in the phrase "Represents a 32-bit signed integer.", and it is caused by the following (decompiled) source code:
//
// Summary:
//     Represents a 32-bit signed integer.
[Serializable]
[ComVisible(true)]
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public struct Int32 : 

However, when I try to get the same thing for my personal class, this seems not to work:
Piece of source code, defining the class:
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Coldstart message
    public class Message_Rec_A_Message : Message

When hovering over such a class:

As you see, there's no message "Coldstart message" in that hint.
How can I get it there?
For your information: I already have built my solution, that did not solve the issue.

Are you aware of documentation comments? The code you saw isn't the "real" code for System.Int32. (See the actual implementation here), What you saw is just a metadata/header thingy that VS generated.

@Sweeper: thanks for your quick reply. I just added this as an example of what I'm looking for. I thought I could learn from that example on how to do this, but clearly it's not that simple.

What you are seeing for Int32 is generated / decompiled code, and it doesn't necessarily conform to how code documentation should be.
For your own example, try the following:
/// <summary>
/// Coldstart message
/// </summary>

Note the number of comment slashes and the XML formatting.
This is called XML Documentation, and you can learn more about this from Microsoft.

This is perfectly what I'm looking for, and you even broke a record: you answered that fast the I need to wait four more minutes before even accepting it :-)

Faster than a speeding bullet, Lois! Happy to help :)
